# Flutter Navigator 2.0

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, navigation, package

My question is related to Navigaror 2.0
There is just a link of medium article on official documentation and nothing else.
I want to implement Activity for Result.But in router deligate class I just implemented push,pop,of methods.
How to implement Future in push,pop I didn't find any lead.
Then I explored the packages on pub.dev
go_router
auto_route
Which package you recommend and why??
Both are up-to-date but I want recommendation from community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My choice is go_router since it's reduce complexity, regardless of the platform and Navigator2 structure and support:

- mobile, web and desktop
- declarative, parameterized routing
- deep and dynamic linking
- nested navigation
- redirection
- custom transitions
- route debugging

and lastly, it provides rapid and excellent support.

Check out this guide for questions about how to implement Activity for Results:

https://gorouter.dev/user-input